# elite troops before

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Russian paratroopers' doomed raid to take airport: Video ***shows elite troops before they were wiped out at battle of Hostomel at the start of invasion*** as Russia admits five were killed in 'special operation'

Source: [Daily Mail](https://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-10606279/Russian-paratroopers-doomed-raid-airport-Video-shows-elite-troops-Hostomel.htm)

---

I think that a *before* clause can't modify a noun.
"***before they were wiped out at battle of Hostomel at the start of invasion***" modifies "***elite troops***".

I regard that as unnatural.
I'd like to know what is your take on that.

Comment: The before clause does not modify elite troops. It **continues** the sentence. The man left the house before his sons were ready to leave.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a time phrase, giving a description of the time that the video shows the troops.  I don't see the "before" phrase as modifying the noun "troops". The expression is "headlinese" but it is natural enough

Compare

> This is a photograph of my brother *when he was five years old*.

That is a natural enough expression, and the "when" clause gives the time of the photograph, it doesn't modify "brother".

Comment: I think that "***Video shows***" in the original post should be "Video showed". I'd like to know what you think about that.

Comment: no,  simple present in the headline.  The video shows these troops.  That is a simple fact so simple presetn